# How to refresh the data in 2 partsstack by selecting a button in non focused part

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

I created a Perspective with 2 partstack and there is active view with focus in one and without focus in another.Is it Possible to refresh the data in a view which dont have a focus but active, by selecting a button in the view which dont have the focus. I dont need to change the focus just needed to refresh the data in both the views according to the button click.

Comment: There is no specific way to do this. You might use the IEventBroker to post an event that the views (and anything else) can receive and respond to.

Comment: While using that both parts are getting focused. I only needed the 2nd partstack focused and data refreshed in both.

Comment: What does 'both parts getting focused' mean? Only one part can have focus. The event broker does not change the focus.

Comment: Both parts from the partstack which are in active state showing focus

Comment: Only one SWT control can have focus - see Display.getFocusControl. Only one MPart can be the active part - see EPartService.getActivePart. In each MPartStack there is one part which is currently selected - see MPartStack.getSelected. Using the event broker does not change any of these.